# Looping through several levels

Tags: r, loops, unique, lapply

I have a naïve understanding of For loops in R. I would appreciate your help to learn it better.
I am working on a project with several tables of data in it. imagine the following structure: `dictionary$table$variables$type`

In the last level (i.e., **type**), the values are FALSE and/or TRUE. I need to show for which **variables** across all the **tables** the value of **type** equals only TRUE or only FALSE or a combination of both.

I found this function to suit my purpose: for instance for a table called HARIX, all values equal FALSE.

```
unique(dictionary$HARIX$variables$type)
[1] FALSE
```

Now I need to turn it into a loop so that it does the job for all the tables included in the dictionary. I don't know how to write this command. I wrote the one below but it doesn't reach the write level I need (i.e., type).

```
value <- list()
for(table_name in project$name){
  value[[table_name]] <- unique(dict[[table_name]]$variables$type)
  print(val[[table_name]])
}
```

I really appreciate your help. If you also have any advice on how to use the lapply function for this purpose, I would love to learn that too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of the for loop and use the map function from the purrr package:

#### Data sample

Remember you have to provide a data sample in order to explain your problem better...

```
v1 <- c(F, F, F)
v2 <- c(F, T, F)
v3 <- c(T, T, T)

dictionary <- list(
  HARIX = list(var1 = list(type = v1), 
               var2 = list(type = v2),
               var3 = list(type = v3)),
  OTHER = list(var4 = list(type = v3), 
               var5 = list(type = v1),
               var6 = list(type = v2)))
```

#### Solution

```
require(purrr)

map(dictionary, ~ map(., ~ map(., unique)))
```

#### Output

```
$HARIX
$HARIX$var1
$HARIX$var1$type
[1] FALSE


$HARIX$var2
$HARIX$var2$type
[1] FALSE  TRUE


$HARIX$var3
$HARIX$var3$type
[1] TRUE



$OTHER
$OTHER$var4
$OTHER$var4$type
[1] TRUE


$OTHER$var5
$OTHER$var5$type
[1] FALSE


$OTHER$var6
$OTHER$var6$type
[1] FALSE  TRUE
```

Here is the [map function documentation](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map.html)

### lapply bonus

You have requested a lapply solution:

```
  lapply(dictionary,
         function(word) lapply(word,
                               function(var) lapply(var, unique)))
```

### Explanation

You have to go down the list till you reach the right level. So you have to use nested map or nested lapply.

Comment: Thank you for the good answer and the bonus! Could you kindly explain a bit about the function (word) and function (var) that you used in lapply? @pietrodito

Comment: Those functions are anonymous, i.e. they have no name. Here `word` and `var` are the names of their arguments.